# ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'mypackage' (unknown location)

Tags: python

I know that there are a low of similar issues, but none helped me, so I am writing a new one. Here is my directory structure:

```
- mypackage
    - __init__.py
- run.py
- requirements.txt
```

The run.py content:

```
from mypackage import app

app.run(host='localhost', port=3648)
```

The mypackage/_*init*_.py content:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
```

And here is the full error:

```
C:\...\parser>python run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mypackage import app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'mypackage' (unknown location)
```

It seems to be a bug or I am doing something wrong..

UPDATE:
Environment check for PYTHONPATH:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])
  File "C:\Users\white\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\os.py", line 678, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'
```

Comment: Can you try adding `__all__ = ['app']` to `___init__.py` ?

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: How about `from .mypackage import app` ?

Comment: Sadly the same result

Comment: Check your `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: Could you help me finding out this environment variable? Thanks.

Comment: `os.environ['PYTHONPATH']` it should contain your working directory

Comment: Error returned. I'll add this error to my question.

Comment: Check this: https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/sys_path.html 
try adding the working directory to `sys.path` or setting `PYTHONPATH` in the environment

Comment: Thanks, I will try those steps.

Comment: It's also possible that this is messed up by something done in a `conftest.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happened to me when Pipenv virtual environment was somehow broken. Deleted the virtualenv and let Pipenv make a new one.

And it worked again.

Comment: I hate that I spent like 2 hours trying to figure it out and this is what worked for me...

Answer (score 13):

tl;dr: rename your package

Was your package really named `mypackage`? I guess not. :)

I had had the same error. In my case, the name I chose for `mypackage` happened to be the name of an existing Python library I didn't know about. 
Once I renamed my package, the error disappeared.

Comment: Before downvoting this answer: Note that it DOES solve the issue in some cases. If it does not solve it in your case, upvote the one that does, or add your own answer. If you just don't like the way it is worded, please suggest a better wording. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

i faced the same problem.
i renamed a few files from init.py to '`__init__.py`'

Comment: you saved me! In my case I didn't have any init files, so just created an empty `__init__.py`, and it fixed the error

Answer (score 4):

To me this happened when installing a local version of a pip package which I wanted to debug. The package was named `mypackage` the same as the folder of which I cloned it via git. You would think that this is not an issue, as it is the default git behavior. But **pip confuses this, if the folder name and the package name is the same.** I renamed the local git clone to `mypackage_git`.

Afterwards I installed via

```
mv mypackage mypackage_git
cd mypackage_git
pip -e .
```

Comment: Thanks! Had exactly the same problem!

Answer (score 3):

I guess when you are running `run.py`, the current aka working directory is not where that file is. So `mypackage` is not on `sys.path`.

Answer (score 0):

One answer that I don't see here is that Python doesn't recognize modules if they're not suffixed with `.py`. In my case, it turned out that the module in question wasn't properly suffixed. If you get this error, check if all of your module files are correctly named.

Answer (score 0):

keep one **init**.py file inside the folder. Then it will import as a Module else it will give same error as unknown location

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I have two feature branches (old, new), I was working on the new branch where old branch is pending merge request from my colleague. After he gave me some feedback I checkout to old branch to fix something first, then went back to the new branch to continue developing. I have forgot the new branch has a `conftest.py` file but the old branch not.

In my old branch, I did not use `conftest.py`, and I mock the tests in the same script that uses it. Unit tests run well.

After that, I merge the old branch into the master branch, then checkout to my new branch, merge master branch into that, then pytest failed. This is because the new branch has `conftest.py` file that mocks away some modules, and that overrides whatever I was mocking inside the old branch's tests.

To solve this, I rethink my unit tests then remove my `conftest.py`, change my ways of mocking, then run the tests again, works as intended.