# ImportError: cannot import name 'SimpleDirectoryReader' from 'llama_index' (unknown location)

Tags: llama-index

```
from llama_index import SimpleDirectoryReader, ServiceContext, VectorStoreIndex
from llama_index.llms import OpenAI
```

Upon trying the above imports I get the following error:

**ImportError: cannot import name 'SimpleDirectoryReader' from 'llama_index' (unknown location)**

Along with:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llama_index.llms'**

I have tried importing llama index via both pip and directly from github.

I am using 0.7.18 version of llama-index.

Answer (score 5):

If you're encountering import errors with llama_index, such as:

ImportError: cannot import name 'SimpleDirectoryReader' from 'llama_index' (unknown location)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llama_index.llms'
And you're using version 0.7.18 of llama-index, **the solution lies in the recent updates to the library**. The structure of imports has been modified, which requires adjusting how you import specific components.

To resolve these import errors, you should update your import statements to reflect the new structure as per the latest documentation. For instance:

```
from llama_index.core import VectorStoreIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader
```

Answer (score 3):

It was deprecated. Use as follows:

```
from llama_index.core import SimpleDirectoryReader, ServiceContext, VectorStoreIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. It occurred as I both imported Jerry's github repo and installed via pip. After renaming the local package as follows, problem solved.

```
mv llama_index llama_index_jerry
cd llama_index_jerry
pip install -e
```

Solution was inspired by this answer:[ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'mypackage' (unknown location)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55657036/importerror-cannot-import-name-app-from-mypackage-unknown-location)